# Can User in Master DB access all other instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a 2 instances in a SQL Server.

[image]

I have some user say `TOPU` in `SERVER1` and he is having role such as `A`,`B` and `C`. I'm not sure whether it is created in `SERVER1` or `MASTER`. Now I'm trying to assign role `C` for same user `TOPU` from `SERVER2` and getting cannot assign role. Now I'm confused whether this user is created in `MASTER` and can be accessed across all instances? Please clarify. Is there any user that can be common across all instance?

Comment: I may greatly misunderstand the question, but SQL server instances (including default instance! - or what is that thing you called master???) are totally separate environments and their users have no relationships between instances.

Comment: A `LOGIN` is a instance object, a `USER` is a database object, @CetinBasoz . You can't create a `LOGIN` for a database. A `LOGIN` can have many `USER`s mapped to it, one in each database. A `LOGIN` cannot be shared across instances, however, they doesn't mean you cannot create the same login on multiple instances, with the same name, password, and SID. If you're using Windows Authentication, then the details of a `LOGIN` like `YourDomain\YourUser` will be the same across all instances in that domain. But, if you `DROP`/`ALTER` the `LOGIN`/`USER` on one instance, it won't effect the others.

Comment: @Larnu, my bad.

Comment: There is a master database on each server/instance. They are not shared.